# CSS: Divs Overlapping Unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

First post, and I'm not highly experienced in CSS. Website (http://www.passivhaustraining.co.uk/) has been working fine for a couple of years, but has suddenly developed a display issue (we were notified today).

When I view in Firefox, the header looks like this (expected behaviour):
[Header as viewed in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnvEs.png)

When I view in Chrome, it looks like this (erroneous behaviour):
[Header as viewed in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJoWD.png)

Until very recently, the header has displayed as expected in both Firefox and Chrome. I have checked the site on the Wayback Machine using Chrome, and historic site captures that were definitely working at the time in Chrome now display incorrectly. This makes me think that Chrome may have recently altered the way it interprets my CSS code.

The HTML for the header is as follows (incomplete, as I need to add some more CSS classes to the style section. However, the problematic ID is included.):

```html
<div class="hgroup full-container ">
<a href="http://www.passivhaustraining.co.uk/" title="Passivhaus Training" rel="home" class="logo"><img src="http://www.passivhaustraining.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Passivhaus-Training.svg"  class="logo-height-constrain"  alt="Passivhaus Training Logo"  /></a>
<div id="header-sidebar" class="no-logo-overlay">
<aside id="custom_html-6" class="widget_text widget widget_custom_html">
<div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img src="http://www.passivhaustraining.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/aecbcarbonlite-e1495805835211.png">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">Managed by WARM: Low Energy Building Practice<br>
on behalf of Passivhaus Trainers and the AECB<br>
<br>
For any queries, contact WARM on:<br>
01752 542 546<br>
training @ peterwarm.co.uk<br>
</div>
</div>
</aside>
</div>
</div>
<style>
<!-- .hgroup.full-container -->
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar aside.widget {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 25px;
</style>
```

Shrinking the Chrome window, such that it mimics the size of a small laptop, tablet or mobile phone, forces the green logo and text to appear below the main site logo, which is as expected.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Liam

Comment: Hi Liam, welcome to SO, please can you create a [mcve] of your problem within the question - with the code you have provided this question will not help future visitors to the site - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Pete I have posted a solution however for reference it is broken on my browser and im using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92

Comment: @Pete Thank you, and sorry for not following protocol. I am doing my best to create a MCV example, but am struggling to extract the relevant classes from the stylesheet, such that the example displays as per the website. Very happy to alter my original post when I have managed to do this. Is there a way I can send over what I have done so far, and get some help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your site on Chrome and it appears that both the elements that make up your header are floated to the left.

If you take this element:

```
<aside id="custom_html-6" class="widget_text widget widget_custom_html">
```

and remove the `float: left` from it the header corrects itself. It looks like it is being applied via your style.css however if you cant remove it for some reason they you could override it with the following:

```
#masthead .hgroup #header-sidebar aside.widget#custom_html-6 {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can confirm this worked for me, too. I will update the live site once I've put a full snippet in my original question. Many thanks.